# Como misturar elementos de dois arrays?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de misturar dois arrays de forma que a exibição deles fique alternando entre os elementos, já tentei um monte coisa e não estou conseguindo. Exemplo figurativo:

Tenho dois arrays com a saída assim:

```
{
   "Registros_1": [
       {
           "nome": "pedro",
           "cpf:": "00000000000",
           "sexo:": "masculino"
       },
       {
           "nome": "daniel",
           "cpf:": "11111111111",
           "sexo:": "masculino"
       }
  ]},
{
     "Registros_2": [
         {
             "nome_empresa": "JD_CARNES",
             "numero:": "00000000000",
             "usuario:": "1111"
         },
         {
             "nome_empresa": "RM_CARROS",
             "numero:": "11111111111",
             "usuario:": "2222"
         }
    ]
}
```

Preciso que saiam assim:

```
{
   "Registros": [
       {
           "nome": "pedro",
           "cpf:": "00000000000",
           "sexo:": "masculino"
       },
       {
           "nome_empresa": "JD_CARNES",
           "numero:": "00000000000",
           "usuario:": "1111"
       },
       {
           "nome": "daniel",
           "cpf:": "11111111111",
           "sexo:": "masculino"
       },
       {
           "nome_empresa": "RM_CARROS",
           "numero:": "11111111111",
           "usuario:": "2222"
       }

  ]
```

}

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Utilize a função array_merge. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Já tentei, essa função une os arrays mas não deixa eles alternados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta implementar uma função para isso:

```
function array_zip(...$arrays) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrays[0]); $i++) {
        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            yield $array[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, se fizer:

```
$array_1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
$array_2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

foreach (array_zip($array_1, $array_2) as $n) {
    echo $n, ' ';
}
```

Sua saída será:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Pois os elementos dos *arrays* serão interpolados.

Para o seu exemplo, ficaria algo como:

```
$resultado = array_zip($Registros_1, $Registros_2);
```

Sendo `$Registros_1` e `$Registros_2` os dois *arrays* que possui.

Comment: Com números funcionou perfeitamente, tentar adaptar de alguma forma aqui

Comment: @PedroSilva para os seus dados também, só não coloquei aqui porque os seus dados se entrada estão muito confusos.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo adaptar!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo não entendo muito bem de PHP porem sei programar em C, no seu caso pelo que eu entendi você teria que colocar alguns comandos de exibição dentro de uma sequencia que vá até o valor total de cadastros efetuados. Na hora da exibição você ira fornecer os dados na sequencia desejada e puxando de fora os dados das variáveis.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

tenta dar uma olhada aqui:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php

Foi onde achei a melhor resposta

Espero ter ajudado